# Арбат и Старый Арбат

Tags: названия

В центре Москвы есть две улицы, очень известные. Это Новый Арбат и Арбат. Можно ли утверждать, что улица Арбат имеет два имени: Арбат и Старый Арбат?

Comment: Есть Санкт-Петербург. Можно ли утверждать, что это Ленинград? Вы сами ответили на свой вопрос: "Это Новый Арбат и Арбат." - и никак больше. Всё остальное это чисто для понимания, уточнения.

Comment: А в случае уточнение необходимо будет писать "Старый" с заглавной буквы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...***влево от него идёт Арбат, который в народе часто называют Старый Арбат, а вправо – Новый Арбат (бывший проспект Калинина).***

https://www.proza.ru/2010/07/14/1163

Таким образом, **официальное** название улиц ***Арбат и Новый Арбат***. А Старый Арбат – название условное, мне кажется, что не все им пользуются. Но в любом случае даже неофициальное название улицы – это имя собственное,  и оно пишется с прописной буквы – Старый Арбат.